# Show hide blurb without using ID's or Classes as content will change frequently

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a CMS that will be updating adding staff members to a site. I have set it up to display a blurb about each member under their corresponding image. I have hidden all of the blurbs onload and only want them displayed once clicked.

Is it possible to remove the unique ID's as the staff members will be add through the CMS and will be changing all of the time.

i also only want to show one blurb at at time, there when one is clicked it will close the other person and only show the correct one.

JS Fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/zangief007/S5G8f/5

CSS:

```
.people{
width:500px;
}
.person{
width:33%;
margin:0 auto;
float:left;
}
.people p{
display:none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="people">

    <div class="person">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
            <h2>John doe</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="person">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
        <h2>Peter Pan</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="person">
       <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
        <h2>Sally Hills</h2>
    </div>

    <p>John Doe is Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque sollicitudin molestie ipsum ut fermentum. Duis adipiscing purus gravida, elementum neque nec, mollis tortor.</p>

    <p>Peter Pan is Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque sollicitudin molestie ipsum ut fermentum. Duis adipiscing purus gravida, elementum neque nec, mollis tortor.</p>

    <p>Sally Hills is Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque sollicitudin molestie ipsum ut fermentum. Duis adipiscing purus gravida, elementum neque nec, mollis tortor.</p>

    <div class="person">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
            <h2>Betty Boo</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="person">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
        <h2>Sm Hunt</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="person">
       <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
        <h2>Paula Walls</h2>
    </div>

    <p>Betty Jones Doe is Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque sollicitudin molestie ipsum ut fermentum. Duis adipiscing purus gravida, elementum neque nec, mollis tortor.</p>

    <p>Sam Hunt is Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque sollicitudin molestie ipsum ut fermentum. Duis adipiscing purus gravida, elementum neque nec, mollis tortor.</p>

    <p>Paula Walls is Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque sollicitudin molestie ipsum ut fermentum. Duis adipiscing purus gravida, elementum neque nec, mollis tortor.</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, however you need to properly re-structure your HTML tag for easier jQuery selection..
Maybe you can put the explanation of a person beside its div, like below:

```
  <div class="person" >
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
            <h2>John doe</h2>

    </div>
    <p>John Doe is Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque sollicitudin molestie ipsum ut fermentum. Duis adipiscing purus gravida, elementum neque nec, mollis tortor.</p>
```

By doing so you can select the correponding `<p>`, using jQuery like below:

```
$(".person").on("click", function(e) { 
    $(".person").each(function(){
        $(this).next("p").fadeOut();
    });
    $(this).next("p").fadeIn();
});
```

Check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S5G8f/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Check this might be helpful for you
[Link Demo][1]

```
[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/S5G8f/10/
```